# How do I read many Json files in pyspark on AWS from the paths in a datafram column?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, pyspark

I need to read a bunch of Json files using pypark, the file paths on S3 are in a dataframe I have.
How do I read all those files in one pyspark script?

Thank you!

the datafram format is as below for an example

```
|id|S3Location                  
+----------------+--------------
|a|s3://path1/path6/yyy.json.gz|
|b|s3://path3/path7/xxx.json.gz|
|c|s3://path3/path8/aaa.json.gz|
|c|s3://path4/path9/bbb.json.gz|
```

Comment: i assume you want to create a dataframe for each of those paths?

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi these are the same schema so i would like to read them all together and create one single dataframe with all of the data

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself-

> pathset=df.select(collect_set("S3Location").alias("paths")).first()["paths"]
>   readjson=sqlContext.read.json(pathset)